# How to interpret scale of mediation results with binary outcome, continuous mediator and binary predictor

Tags: r

I am using the `mediate` function from the 'mediation' package to perform mediation following the Baron-Kenny procedure on data with a binary intervention (X), covariate (X2), continuous mediator (M) and a binary outcome (Y).

I fit the following mock models:

```
    data <- data.frame(X=rbinom(100, size=1, prob=0.5), M=rnorm(100,15,5), Y=rbinom(100, size=1, prob=0.1),
                   X2=rnorm(100,5,1))

    step1 <- glm(Y ~ X + X2, family = "binomial", data = data) 
    step2 <-  lm(M ~ X + X2, data = data) 
    step3 <- glm(Y ~ X + M + X2, family = "binomial", data = data)
```

Estimate mediation effect:

```
    library(mediation)
    med <- mediate(step2, step3, treat="X", mediator="M", boot=T)
    summary(med)
    
Causal Mediation Analysis 

Nonparametric Bootstrap Confidence Intervals with the Percentile Method

                         Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value
ACME (control)            0.00307     -0.01265         0.03    0.78
ACME (treated)            0.00377     -0.01590         0.03    0.78
ADE (control)             0.03508     -0.10802         0.18    0.59
ADE (treated)             0.03578     -0.11168         0.19    0.59
Total Effect              0.03885     -0.09931         0.19    0.55
Prop. Mediated (control)  0.07896     -1.55604         1.63    0.88
Prop. Mediated (treated)  0.09697     -1.38302         1.63    0.88
ACME (average)            0.00342     -0.01387         0.03    0.78
ADE (average)             0.03543     -0.11037         0.18    0.59
Prop. Mediated (average)  0.08796     -1.52774         1.65    0.88

Sample Size Used: 100 


Simulations: 1000
```

My question is, what is the scale for the total (Total Effect) and direct effects (ADE) in the summary? Are they odds that need to be exponentiated?

Comment: There is no apparent connection between the example data you offer and the output that you show.

Comment: Apologies. Fixed.

Comment: How are you getting `ACME (control)`, `ACME(treated)` , `ADE(control)`, `ADE(treated)` in the output when they are not in the input? <strike>Maybe I don't</strike> I didn't understand the question. (I did vote to migrate to CrossValidated.com with the rationale that is sounds more like a methods question, anyway.)